# Не отображается график в vscode (ml)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

При запуске выдаёт картинку в центре написано "js". Не могу решить проблему, помогите пожалуйста

Код:

```
import shap
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier

data = pd.read_csv('D:/train_for_an.csv')

X = data.drop('Survived', axis=1)
y = data['Survived']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=7, learning_rate=0.1, depth=3)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

score = model.score(X_test, y_test)
shap.initjs()
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model, data = X)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train)
```

После этой строки выводит "js"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]